# Build app in a way to bypass rate-limits of 3rd party API

Tags: architecture, software-design

I want to build an app that is constantly fetching data from a 3rd party API (binance) in this case to perform actions on the data and return it to my front-end.

The API's rate limit don't allow me to easily archieve what I want to do which is the following:

Example project description: Binance holds 2000+ market pairs. Each pair can be charted on different timeframes (5 minutes, 10 minutes, hourly and so on).

I need to get data for every trading pair and every timeframe. So basically for market X/Y I would need to make 5 requests to get the data for 5minutes, 10minutes, 15minutes, 30minutes, hourly.

The rate limit is 1200 req/m.

I was now thinking about the best approach to design my backend in order to be able to fetch all the data without getting rate limited in the most speedy mannor.

I was thinking to build a microservice for every timeframe and a gateway the front-end connects to.

Is this the best approach for what I am looking for to do?

Example:
microservice-5m fetches 5minute data every minute for all market pairs on binance
microservice-15m fetches 5minute data every minute for all market pairs on binance
microservice-30m fetches 5minute data every minute for all market pairs on binance

gateway keeps a cache of the microservice responses and forwards to the front-end.

I am not sure if I am able to express myself good enough in english in order for you to understand. I am sorry in advance.

Comment: Rate limiting is a type of licensing, it's there to ensure that resources are available for everybody, that you pay for licenses if you need more requests, etc. Really the best answer here is to "pay for it", otherwise you're asking us to help you circumvent the hard work of developers. If the rate limiting is any good, they'll catch this and ban you anyway.

Comment: true. In this case I dont think there is a way to buy more requests but I will check it out. Thank you